# Define variable as ParentClass and pass it to a function that accepts ChildrenClassA and ChildrenClassB

Tags: c#

I have a

```
public abstract ParentClass{}
```

and

```
public ChildrenClassA: ParentClass{}
public ChildrenClassB: ParentClass{}
```

And want to define a variable in some other class:

```
ParentClass parentClass;
```

And pass it as a parameter to a Function with overload:

```
Function(ChildrenClassA arg){}
Function(ChildrenClassB arg){}
```

So I can do:

```
Function(parentClass);
```

And it would execute different code depending on what subClass the variable is.

The problem I have is that no overload was defined for ParentClass, and if I make one the function always executes the ParentClass overload, even if I'm passing one of the children classes to it.

Is there any other way to fix it other than defining the Function so it recives ParentClass and an IF statement inside checking for what children class it is?

Do you know if I'm making some design mistake if I keep running into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is no “ other way to fix it other than defining the Function so it recives ParentClass and an IF statement inside checking for what children class it is”.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create another class like below:**

```
public class GroupClass 
    {
        public ChildrenClassA ChildrenClassA { get; set; }
        public ChildrenClassB ChildrenClassB { get; set; }
    }


Your_Function(GroupClass args)
{
var childrenClassA = args.ChildrenClassA;
var childrenClassB = args.ChildrenClassB;
};
```

You can also access your ParentClass property inside your function;